# Wrong map api key release in play store

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

**Edit: solved by myself 10 minutes after asking (see answer; I leave the question here for people with the same problem and I'll close it as soon as I can answer it by myself)**

Released app with wrong maps api key and now it's impossible to solve this problem for people who already downloaded the app

Setup: Android App (Api Level 8+), Google Maps V2, SupportMapFragment (com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment)

Problem: I released an update (let's call it V1.0.1) for my app, which had the debug (hence wrong) maps api key in it's manifest.

Those, who had the previous version on their phone (V1.0) could install the update without any problem (map was shown). However, those who installed the app for the first time (so V1.0.1 was their first install), had a gray map (since it's the wrong api key). 
No Problem - I thought - let's make an V1.0.2 with the correct api key. Lets assume, everybody updated to Version 1.0.2, we now have three groups. People with first install:

- V1.0: still everything is fine
- V1.0.2: everything's fine
- V1.0.1: still the gray map (and here's the problem)

Android seems to cache the maps api key from the first install. Is it possible to "reset" this, so I don't have to tell all people who installed with V1.0.1 to delete and reinstall?

This seems to be a bug in the google maps concept since it's not even possible to declare an "debug api key" and a seperate "release api key"

Comment: You have experienced a side effect of [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :D

Comment: @user1915477 you can post as answer.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: haha, normally yes, but this time, it came to me ten minutes after I wrote the post while reading something completely different (lets call it "Taking a Dump Debugging"; it's a thing)
Besides: I always use Rubber Duck Debugging, before I ask the crowd, but even talking with my co developers didn't solve it this time :-)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: nope, it still says "your reputation is to low, wait 4h"

Comment: Oops. Enjoy your time in SO by start picking a user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 10 minutes after writing this post, I figured it out by myself (after five days of searching and googling): I used two different api keys (one for development, one for the release). At the end: that's stupid, since you can have several app hashes attached to one key. Hence that's the solution, **just added on code.google.com/apis/console the release hash to the development api key (for backwards compatibility) and the development hash to the release api key (for easier development).** I hope, this helps somebody with the same problem.